# Jquery will not return an object (Drupal)

Tags: jquery, object, element

For some reason Jquery is not returning objects in this function.  I have no idea why.  Part of what makes this so frustrating is that I have a completely separate function just below it that works just fine and uses the exact same syntax but instead returns an object as expected.  For this function I am getting nothing but problems :(

```
Drupal.behaviors.nutriListen = {
attach: function () {

    $('input.form-autocomplete').on('blur', function () {

        console.log(this);
        console.log($('input.form-autocomplete').attr());

        var id = $('input.form-item-recipe-ingredients-quantity').id;
        console.log(id);

    }

    );

    }
}
```

On the log the returned information is the html element.

```
 <input id="edit-recipe-ingredients-ing-0-name" class="form-item-recipe-    ingredients-name form-text form-autocomplete" type="text" data-thmr="thmr_132" maxlength="128" size="25" value="" name="recipe_ingredients[ing][0][name]" autocomplete="OFF" aria-autocomplete="list">
```

The $().attr is broken, crashes jquery, and the $().id is undefined.  Any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: when in doubt, check the jQuery API. Would have saved yourself a trip here. http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for :

```
$('input.form-autocomplete').attr("id");
```

You need to tell the `attr()` function what attribute you are looking for. `$(...).id` isn't working because `$(...)` returns a jQuery selection (an array of nodes), you could use `$(...)[0].id`. Also if the `console.log(this)` is working then you can just do :

```
id = $(this).attr("id");
console.log(id);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: last part is incorrect...`this` within jQuery event handlers is native DOM element and must be wrapped in `$()` to use jQuery methods. I think you meant `this.id`